# railsでcssやjsを1つのファイルにまとめたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

railsでcssやjsを1つのファイルにまとめたいのですがどうしたら良いのでしょうか。

scssの数だけ、CoffeeScriptの数だけhtmlに読み込みのタグが追加されて、たった数行のコードためにリクエストが発生するのが嫌です。

ただ、railsらしくcssとjsのファイルそれぞれ1つのファイルにする方法というのがわからないので教えていただけないでしょうか。

今はguardで1つのファイルにまとめたものを静的なコードで読みこむように指定しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

development.rbやproduction.rbに以下設定をすればいける気がします。

```
config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

Answer (score 0):

`Asset Pipeline`という機能で、Production環境であればデフォルトで一つのファイルにminifyされますよ。

明示的に無効にしないかぎりは有効になってるはずです。

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: 例えばjqueryなどの外部ライブラリも1つにしたい場合はどうしたらよいのでしょうか。